# Using `grep` From List in For-Loop

Tags: bash, list, for-loop, grep

Is it possible to use `grep` on an array of parameters to check in file? For example:

```
 #!/bin/bash

 counter=0
 property_list=( "main.memory" "jvm.memory" ...)
 for i in "${property_list[@]}"
 do 
     for mLine in $(grep "${propert_list[counter]}" params.properties)
     do
            echo "$mLine"

     done
     let counter=counter+1
 done
```

This format for `grep` in the for loop doesn't work as it takes more properties than needed (probably because of the white spaces in the file). 
Furthermore, the property format in the file is `main.memory=-min50m -max1024m`.
The `for` loop returns in a Non List format loops twice and returns `max1024m`, ideally I'd like to have both min and max saved to different variables, but one bridge at a time....

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed to `awk`:

```
for mLine in $(awk "/${property_list[counter]}/" params.properties)
do
    echo "$mLine"
done
```